# Android Room efficient way to insert objects of different types

Tags: android, android-room

We have a database with ~50 different entity classes.
Data is fetched from server and should then be inserted into the database.
What **I want to avoid** is something like that:

```
if (data instanceof Apple) {
   AppDatabase.instance().appleDao().insert(data);
} else if (data instanceof Orange) {
   AppDatabase.instance().orangeDao().insert(data);
} else if (...)
... 50 more of this ...
```

Is there a better/generic approach to that?
I am migrating the code from the Realm ORM, which has a `Realm.insert(data)` which figures out the correct "table" itself.

Comment: Not sure to understand what your goal. If you have 50 different entity, at some point, you gonna have to chose which local entity you want insert your data... I you have access to all your Pojo, I would inside a push method to insert it. Like this, no god insert but all Pojo manage it self where to insert.

Comment: @TeddySmith Not a bad idea, although it runs a bit against the DAO approach, Room is using.Unfortunately, it will not work with my problem (I over-simplified the example I'm afraid), because actually, `data` isn't a single object but a list of objects. Otherwise, your suggestion would probably work out.